# Dovecot antispam plugin does not get triggered

Tags: dovecot, dspam

I've got an issue with the antispam plugin using dovecot 2.1.7 and dspam 3.10.1.

I think, the antispam plugin does not recognize the Junk-Folder because the log reports

```
Mar 25 13:11:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_spam(Junk): 0
```

and after finding very few results with Google I'm quite sure, the output should be

mailbox_is_spam(Junk): 1

The dovecot antispam configuration is as follows:

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins antispam
}


plugin {
  antispam_debug_target = stdout
  antispam_verbose_debug = 1

  antispam_backend = dspam
  antispam_signature = X-DSPAM-Signature
  antispam_signature_missing = error

  antispam_trash = Trash
  antispam_spam = Junk

  antispam_dspam_binary = /usr/bin/dspam
  antispam_dspam_args = --client;--user=%u;--source=error
}
```

When manually moving a message to the Junk-Folder with Thunderbird this happens:

```
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_unsure(Junk): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_trash(INBOX): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_trash(Junk): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mail copy: from trash: 0, to trash: 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_spam(INBOX): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_spam(Junk): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mailbox_is_unsure(INBOX): 0
Mar 25 13:24:22 mail imap: antispam: mail copy: src spam: 0, dst spam: 0, src unsure: 0

Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: plugin initialising (2.0-notgit)
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: verbose debug enabled
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: "Junk" is exact match spam folder
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: no unsure folders
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: "Trash" is exact match trash folder
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: dspam binary set to /usr/bin/dspam
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: dspam extra arg --client
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: dspam extra arg --user=vmail
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: dspam extra arg --source=error
Mar 25 13:24:31 mail imap: antispam: signature header line is "X-DSPAM-Signature"
```

But checking with `dspam_stats` does not suggest that any training is done.

Thanks for your help,
  Ralph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my setup had two misconfigurations in it.

**The first**

My virtual users inboxes are located at

```
/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<username>
```

and **not**

```
/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<username>/.INBOX
```

The Junk-folder location is

```
/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<username>/.Junk
```

**but (or therefor)** the IMAP namespace INBOX points to

```
/var/mail/vhosts/<domain>/<username>/.INBOX
```

and my configuration has to be

```
antispam_spam = INBOX/Junk
```

**The second** misconfiguration is not actually related to the question, but I will post the answer anyway:

The `dspam` command argument is `--user <username>` and not `--user=<username>` (the equal sign is erroneous) and therefor the configuration must be:

```
antispam_dspam_args = --client;--source=error;--user;%u
```

instead of

```
antispam_dspam_args = --client;--user=%u;--source=error
```

Comment: I had to wait 2 days before I was able to accept it.